# New @ViewScoped bean created for each h:form

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a problem with `@ViewScoped` beans created multiple times for different forms on the page.

I created a simple test page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="f1">
        <h:commandButton value="action 1" action="#{testController.action}">
            <f:ajax />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="f2">
        <h:commandButton value="action 2" action="#{testController.action}">
            <f:ajax />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and a backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestController() {
        System.out.println("TestController created");
    }

    public String action() {
        System.out.println("action() invoked");
        return null;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("serialization");
        out.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("deserialization");
        in.defaultReadObject();
    }
}
```

And here is web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebTest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

When I click the `action 1` button, a new `TestController` bean is created and then serialized with `writeObject` method. Then, when I click `action 2` button, I expect that it will be deserialized, but instead, a new bean is created and those two beans act independently for each `<h:commandButton>`.

I encoutered this problem with both Mojarra and Myfaces, so I guess it's not a bug in the library.

Maybe I did some dumb mistake or missed something, but shouldn't `@ViewScoped` bean be the only bean for current view regardless of the number of `<h:form>` on the page?

**UPDATE:** I found out that the problem disappears when removing `<f:ajax>` tags; unfortunately, this is not the option for me.

**UPDATE 2:** I think I found the cause of the problem: when using multiple forms, only request form's `ViewState` is automatically updated. In my example, if I send request using the first form, the second form's view state is not updated unless I add `render=":f2"` to `<f:ajax>` in the first form. And since `@ViewScoped` bean is stored in the view state, the second form's view state will not include this bean and therefore a new bean will be created when sending request from the second form. So if my reasoning is true, I must manually update all forms in the view using `render` attribute to keep view states identical across forms. But this seems inconvenient especially if there are a lot of forms on the page. Aren't there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The code posted so far doesn't do that. At least, not for me on a default JSF playground project.

The symptoms are however recognizeable as when you would bind a view scoped bean property to any attribute of a taghandler like JSTL `<c:forEach>`, Facelets `<ui:include>`, JSF `<f:attribute>`,  or to the `id` or `binding` attribute of a JSF UI component.

Any EL expressions in tag handler attributes and `id` and `binding` attributes of UI components are executed during building and restoring the view. When restoring the view during a postback, the view scoped beans are only available *after* restoring the view (because they're stored in there). So they were not available at the moment the view is restored and that explains why they are constructed everytime.

#### See also:

- [`@ViewScoped` fails in taghandlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)

Comment: Thanks, I've read your article, but as you can see, I don't use any of mentioned tags or attributes. I also tried setting javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false but this didn't help. Also updated the original post to include the full page and web.xml.